# Security standard for web-based Tele-Radiology software

Tags: penetration-test

I am preparing a test plan for the security penetration testing of a software solution that manages patient information (HIPAA compliance) and allow the user to access to it from the web. Does anyone happen to know if there is any security standard for HIPAA that I can refer to as a blueprint for building the test plan?

Ly

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're in the U.S., and are a Covered Entity, since you refer to HIPAA and are storing patient information.

First off, note that the HITECH act and related federal guidance put significantly more detailed guidance on the table; much more than the "reasonable effort" HIPAA guidance, and involving much more serious action in the case of a breach.

If you can afford it, get a consultant who specializes in the area.  You'll need a lawyer who knows the area whether you have a consultant or not.

For official HIPAA/HITECH guidance, as a bare minimum, start with HHS (Health and Human Services), NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology), and FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standards) - I've outlined a few high points below - this list is in no way complete nor comprehensive - it's merely a starting point!

[HHS.gov Health Information Privacy](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/)

[HHS.gov Security Rule Guidance Material](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/securityruleguidance.html)

[HHS.gov Understanding Health Information Privacy](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/)

[HHS.gov Breach Notification Rule](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/breachnotificationrule/) - this is one of the most critical pages, as it links to important Federal Register articles.

- [Breach Notification Guidance and RFI (74 FR 19006)](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/coveredentities/federalregisterbreachrfi.pdf) is the first; in particular, page 19010 refers you to various [NIST Special Publications](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html)

  - NIST SP 800-52 Guidelines for the Selection, Configuration, and Use of Transport Layer Security (TLS) Implementations is called out specifically; [Rev.1 is currently in draft](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-52-rev1/draft_sp800_52_r1.pdf) to replace the old version - READ IT.

    - Assess your web server and all other TLS system cipher suite choices - you can use [Qualys SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) for free to see the list of cipher suites your server supports; compare those against what's allowed in SP 800-52.
  - [Breach Notification Interim Final Regulation (74 FR 42740)](http://edocket.access.gpo.gov/2009/pdf/E9-20169.pdf) is another link on the 74 FR 19006 chain
- [Also see Omnibus HIPAA Rulemaking](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/omnibus/index.html)

Other [NIST Special Publications](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html) of interest include, but are not limited to:

- [SP 800-131A Transitions: Recommendation for Transitioning the Use of Cryptographic Algorithms and Key Lengths](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-131A/sp800-131A.pdf) came out Jan 2011, and almost all of the cutoff dates have already passed.

  - I haven't seen specific reference to SP 800-131A in the Federal Register documents, but it contains extremely good guidance, and certainly wouldn't be something you'd want to explain having ignored, on national media, after a breach
  - RSA < 2048 bits is no longer "Acceptable"
  - DSA with |p| < 2048 or |q| < 224 is no longer "Acceptable"
  - EC < 224 is no longer "Acceptable"
  - SHA-1 is no longer "Acceptable" for digital signature generation or digital signature verification.

    - It IS still "Acceptable" for non-digital signature applications, including in particular HMAC based KDF's.
  - HMAC < 112 bits is no longer "Acceptable"
- [SP 800-111 Guide to Storage Encryption Technologies for End User Devices](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-111/SP800-111.pdf) is specifically mentioned in 74 FR 19006
- [SP 800-77 Guide to IPsec VPNs](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-77/sp800-77.pdf) is specifically mentioned in 74 FR 19006
- [SP 800-113 Guide to SSL VPNs](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-113/SP800-113.pdf) is specifically mentioned in 74 FR 19006
- SP 800-88 Guidelines for Media Sanitization Rev.1 is in [draft](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsDrafts.html) at this time, and is specifically mentioned in 74 FR 19006

[FIPS 140-2 Annex A: Approved Security Functions for FIPS PUB 140-2, Security Requirements for Cryptographic Modules](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf) is specifically mentioned in 74 FR 19006.

- Note that DSA/ElGamal GPG and PGP keys do not qualify as FIPS 140-2 compliant - not only is ElGamal not listed, the DSA keys are almost always 1024 bit, which is too short per NIST SP 800-131A (above).